# Media Query Triggering when it should not?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have this [test page](https://superfly-css.github.io/superfly-css-component-button/deploy/test/html/).  Within it there's a `.Test_container` class that is supposed to have a flex box column layout unless the minimum width is 768 px.  This is the media query rule that is supposed to kick in at 768 px.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) index.css:1
 .u-md-flex-row {
     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal!important;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal!important;
      -ms-flex-direction: row!important;
      flex-direction: row!important;
 }
```

If I uncheck `flex-direction: row then the layout renders in a column.  If I view the page on my cell phone or shrink the width below 768 px, then media query is still in effect.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the meta tag in your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Tried and Tested with your test page

Answer (score 0):

Why you have all rules with !important? You must try to avoid that if you can. If you cant, anyway, I think you can use this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal !important;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal !important;
    -ms-flex-direction: row !important;
    flex-direction: row !important; 
}
```

I can't test it right now but it should work

Comment: I tried adding `only screen` to the media query but it did not make any difference and if I delete the responsive utility class completely then the layout changes to column layout, so the responsive utility is triggered at smaller viewports sizes but I don't think it should be...

Answer (score 0):

**this should work** try to understand the media query syntax
 there was problem with your syntax and you do not use important ifyou not required

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
.u-md-flex-row {
     -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
     -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
      flex-direction: row;
 }
}
```